# TF custom OP on GPU - Tensor inputs work fine, int inputs fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting, operator-overloading

I write a custom OP for TF (with c++ and a cuda kernel) that runs on GPU. A toy identity-OP runs fine, it relies on `tf::Tensor` inputs and outputs, and then simply copies elements from input tensors to output ones.

However when I try to pass `int` inputs (a single `int` number) I get a segmentation fault. In the `REGISTER_OP` declaration I use

```
`.Input( "image_size: int32"   )`
```

and then in `void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {` I try to read this `int` argument, first as a `tf::Tensor` and then to convert to `int`.

```
const Tensor& inn_image_size_T = context->input(0);
auto inn_image_size_Tflat = inn_image_size_T.flat<int>();
int  inn_image_size = inn_image_size_Tflat(0);
```

This is in compliance with samples I find online, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/bahaako/data_augmentation_for_volumetric_images/blob/282de6f0ad0f7fdd4dc714337315e2b01ad759ae/ddtn/ddtn/cuda/CPAB_ops.cc) (relevant lines: 46, 70).

The Op has been checked and runs normally on the GPU without the last line (`int  inn_image_size = inn_image_size_Tflat(0);`), and for the tensor arguments indeed inputs are copied to outputs.

However for the int arguments, when I try to convert from an int-Tensor to int, things compile but when I run I get a segmentation fault.

Any hint why this happens?

=========================================================

=======================================      Updates:

=========================================================

I also print for sanity check `inn_image_size_T.NumElements()` and `inn_image_size_T.size()` and the result is `1` as expected, since I pass just a single number. So the information seems to be there, but reading it is unexpectedly problematic.

Comment: The result is exactly the same, segmentation fault. I changed from `(` to `[` just for experimentation, my bad. I edited the original post back to the paranthesis version.

Comment: Did you really pass an int32. Python/NumPy default is int64! Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, the input is indeed int32, good point.